# my equation breaks into two rows

Tags: syntax

I have the following problem: These equations don't compose into a single line, instead, they break into two lines each of them. There must be a problem with my syntax but I can't seem to find it, I hope you can detect it:

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{equation}
    \alpha(\frac{K_{t}^g}{N_{t}})^\psi   A_{t}    K_{t}^\((\alpha - 1)\) L_{t}^\((1-\alpha)\)   =  r_{t}
  \end{equation}
\end{center} 

\begin{center}
  \begin{equation}
    (1-\alpha) (\frac{K_{t}^g}{N_{t}})^\psi A_{t} K_{t}^\alpha L_{t}^\(-\alpha\) = w_{t}
  \end{equation}
\end{center}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: What is the purpose of `center`? Without it you still get the horizontally centered equation. :-)

Comment: it's usually not a good idea to use consecutive separate `equation`s (or unnumbered with `\[ ... \]`).  the result can be really uneven vertical spacing, and lack of control over page breaks.  some "grouping" structures are available with the `amsmath` package (for the user's guide, `texdoc amsldoc`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed a syntax problem:

```
K_{t}^\((\alpha - 1)\)
```

The expression is already inside math, instead curly braces are used for grouping the superscript:

```
K_{t}^{(\alpha - 1)}
```

Or the full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \alpha\left(\frac{K_{t}^g}{N_{t}}\right)^\psi
  A_{t} K_{t}^{(\alpha - 1)}
  L_{t}^{(1-\alpha)}   =  r_{t}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  (1-\alpha) \left(\frac{K_{t}^g}{N_{t}}\right)^\psi
  A_{t} K_{t}^\alpha
  L_{t}^{-\alpha} = w_{t}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remarks:

- The equation environments are not affected by environment `center`, they are already centered by default.
- `\left` and `\right` can be used with different kind of delimiters to get the right size of the symbols (thanks [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114543/my-equation-breaks-into-two-rows/114544?noredirect=1#comment252909_114544)).

And a variant with reduced horizontal spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \alpha\mleft(\frac{K_{t}^g}{N_{t}}\mright)^{\!\psi}
  A_{t} K_{t}^{(\alpha - 1)}
  L_{t}^{(1-\alpha)}   =  r_{t}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  (1-\alpha) \mleft(\frac{K_{t}^g}{N_{t}}\mright)^{\!\psi}
  A_{t} K_{t}^\alpha
  L_{t}^{-\alpha} = w_{t}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remarks:

- `\!` is a small negative space that it is used to move `\psi` more closely to the closing right parenthesis.
- The variants `\mleft` and `\mright` of package `mleftright` avoids the additional horizontal space introduced by `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to Latex and this tips and remarks will help a lot :)

Comment: You may also want to make LaTeX insert larger parentheses around `\frac{K_{t}^g}{N_{t}}`; I'd use `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`.